# php mail() prints mysterious error

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm trying to use the mail function in PHP, and it simply yeilds this mysterious error in the error log:

```
sh: 1: -t: not found
```

I have both sendmail and mailutils installed, as well as set the sendmail path in php.ini.

I've looked at [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/PHP_mail()), and I tried the suggested fixes there with no change.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the sendmail_path set to in php.ini?  It should look something like this if you are on a Unix system.

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

It sounds like the "/usr/sbin/sendmail" piece is missing.

Comment: This partly correct, the issue was that the path to sendmail was incorrect.